# CMake: Dependencies of an external project

Tags: c++, cmake, dependency-management

I'm wondering how to manage dependencies of an external project. Let's say I have three projects, each one in a different repository:

1. **Core**: library exporting a lot of useful stuff.
2. **Lib1**: library with some specific classes (depends on **Core**).
3. **Executable**: uses stuff from **Core** and also from **Lib1**.

Each project with its CMakeLists.txt. Using find_package and defining paths on CMake I can build each project without problems and install it (I followed [this tuto](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file) to build .cmake files for libraries)

---

Now I'm trying to make this process as easy as possible and I'm introducing the ExternalProject_Add macro, this way people will only have to clone **Executable** repository and with the help of CMake files **Lib1** and **Core** are also downloaded, compiled and linked.

The problem is that **Executable** and **Lib1** depends on **Core** but I want it to be cloned (and compiled) only once. Here is the problem:

- In **Executable** CMake clones and builds **Core** with the ExternalProject_Add features.
- Then Cmake clones **Lib1** and look for **Core** but it hasn't been already installed so there is no *core-targets.cmake* file (*core-config.cmake* is available)... and building fails...

---

I don't know if there is a documented way to work with this kind of project tree or shall I write some kind of workaround when **Core** is included as dependency of an external project in order to avoid the use of core-targets.cmake file.

Thanks!

---

**Solution**

I realized that when using ExternalProject_Add it downloads, builds and INSTALL the project so, in the install-folder, I already have all the files needed to compile its dependants.

So I can manage this issue following these steps (also for build order):

- *ExternalProject_Add* for **Core**
- *ExternalProject_Add* for **Lib1** passing Core install_dir as argument
- ...and **Executable**.

Comment: Two alternatives I see: (1) make a single CMake project for all your libs and executable; (2) make `Executable` only depend on `Lib1`.

Comment: (copied as solution)

I realized that when using ExternalProject_Add it downloads, builds and INSTALL the project so, in the install-folder, I already have all the files needed to compile its dependants.

So I can manage this issue following these steps (also for build order):
 * ExternalProject_Add for Core
 * ExternalProject_Add for Lib1 passing Core install dir as argument.
 * ..and Executable.

(copied in the question)

Answer (score 1):

I would add two convenience projects to **Executable**, which would be contained in subfolders and make use of `ExternalProject_Add`.

```
add_subdirectory( CoreWrapper ) # Use ExternalProject_Add here
add_subdirectory( Lib1Wrapper ) # Use ExternalProject_Add here
```

Now you can either add dependencies to **Executable**, so that everything gets installed before **Executable** is build or you work directly with the binaries contained in the build folders.